# SASS Grid Layout

Tags: css, sass, scss, style

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, что-то не могу найти, как включить в sass, чтобы он квадратные скобки нормально понимал?

У меня есть в стилях что-то вроде

```
grid-template-columns: [page-start] 1fr 1280px 1fr [page-end];
```

Но sass ругается

```
error main.scss (Line 216: Invalid CSS after "...plate-columns: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "[page-start] 1f...")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, решил проблему

```
grid-template-columns: #{"[page-start] 1fr 1280px 1fr [page-end]"};
```

Comment: Вы можете принять свой ответ.